# How to save one row to an array

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to assign a few values from a set range to an array. My array is databaseLine and it is dimmed as a Variant. I keep getting an Application Defined or Object-Defined Error on this line. I'm pretty sure its my syntax somewhere.

A few explanations:

- sht is just the sheet i'm working
- rackCells.Row is the specific row I wan to pull data from

`databaseLine = sht.Range("C13:O10012").Rows(rackCell.Row).Range("C:M").Value`

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally,

```
Dim rngArray
rngArray = Range("A1:B2").Value
```

Your case

```
databaseLine = sht.Range("C13:O10012").Range("C" & rackCell.Row & ":M" & rackCell.Row).Value
```

Comment: Ah I see.
I needed to specify the row along with the column as well.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you reference rackCells.Row in the text, but use rackCell.row in the line of code.

Answer (score 0):

Without using string arrangement, you can use:

```
databaseLine = Intersect(sht.Rows(rackCell.Row), sht.Range("C:M")).Value
```

sht.Range("C13:O10012") is redundant.